# how can we solve this linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an n×n matrix such that $A^4=I_n$ and let $M=A^3+A^2+A+I_n$.

a)Show that $A$ is non-singular.

b)Show that $(A-I_n)(A^3+A^2+A+I_n)$=O.

c) If $|M|≠0$, show that $A=I_n$.

Comment: Hint for (a):  $AA^3=I$

Comment: Hint for (b):  multiply it out

Answer (score 0):

As per what's given:

a) see that since $A^4=I_n \Rightarrow |A^4|=1 \Rightarrow |A|^4=1$ so $|A|\ne0$,i.e. non-singular.

b)simple algebra

c)see that since b) is true $\Rightarrow (A-I_n)M=\mathbf{O}\;$ and $|M|\ne0 \Rightarrow M $ is inevertible. Let $M^{-1}$ be the inverse. $\Rightarrow (A-I_n)MM^{-1}=\mathbf{O}M^{-1}\;\Rightarrow(A-I_n)=\mathbf{O}$

Answer (score 0):

For part (b), here's a faster way:

$A^4=I_n \Rightarrow A^4=I_n^4\Rightarrow A^4-I_n^4=\mathbf{O}$

But $A^4-I_n^4=(A-I_n)(A^3+A^2I_n+AI^2_n+I^3_n)=(A-I_n)(A^3+A^2+A+I_n)$, so you are done.

Comment: The above is actually a standard factorisation of difference of powers.